sympy matrix scientific notation
I'm trying to display a sympy matrix in scientific notation, and it is only working for values less than 1. I can't understand why applyfunc is behaving differently. Is there a better way to do this?
import numpy as np
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy.printing import latex
from IPython.display import display

C = np.array([
    [390, 145, ],
    [145, 0, ],
    ])*1e9

S_ij = np.linalg.inv(C)
S_scientific = Matrix(S_ij).applyfunc(lambda x: '{:.2e}'.format(float(x)))
print('this prints as desired:')
display(S_scientific) #m^2 / N 

def g(x):
    #shouldn't be necessary since 0 handles fine above
    if abs(float(x.evalf())) < 1e-10:
        return '0'
    else:
        return f'{float(x.evalf(8)):.2e}'
C_scientific = Matrix(C).applyfunc(g)
print()
print('this is not print in scientific notation:')
display(C_scientific) 
print(C_scientific)

And the output is, with a check on the function g:


Are you using sympy only to attempt to print the results the way you want, or to actually perform some computation with sympy?

Both, to print and perform computation, but thirdly, with sympy.printing.latex, it makes it really easy to display the matrix or other sympy object in streamlit

I just want you to know that the solution that you accepted is going to alter the results/precisions of your computation, because you have effectively rounded the numbers. I'll attempt to give you a different solution later...

I don't use SimPy but it seems this might be a workaround for you.
Here for every matrix entry you force a desired precision with Float(number, precision). I guess if you don't make it by hand, SimPy falls back to its standard precision which results in large numbers.
import numpy as np
from sympy import Matrix, Float

def formatter(x):
    return Float(x, 3)

m = np.array([152000.0])
m = Matrix(m).applyfunc(formatter)


The problem with your attempt, and the other answer, is that the elements of the new Matrix returned by applyfunc are different. You are losing precision, for the sake of printing.
What you want to do is to modify the way the original matrix is printed.
For numpy matrices, you can execute this at the beginning:
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

Then:
S_ij
# array([[-1.76e-28,  6.90e-12],
#        [ 6.90e-12, -1.85e-11]])

C
# array([[3.90e+11, 1.45e+11],
#        [1.45e+11, 0.00e+00]])

For sympy matrices, you need to modify the appropriate printer. I'm going to show how to modify the Latex printer in order to achieve scientific notation for floating point numbers. At the beginning, execute this:
from sympy import *
from sympy.printing.latex import LatexPrinter
import numpy as np

class MyLatexPrinter(LatexPrinter):
    def __init__(self, settings=None):
        self._default_settings.update({
                "float_precision": 5
            }
        )
        super().__init__(settings)
    
    def _print_Float(self, expr):
        s = np.format_float_scientific(expr, precision=self._settings["float_precision"])
        mant, exp = s.split("e")
        return mant + r"\cdot" + "10^{%s}" % exp

def my_latex(expr, **settings):
    return MyLatexPrinter(settings).doprint(expr)

init_printing(use_latex=True, latex_printer=my_latex, float_precision=2)

Then:
Matrix(S_ij)


Matrix(C)


As you can see, we are off to a good start. But you can improve it further by catching the special cases, like removing + when the exponent is positive, dealing with 0 (zero), infinity, etc.
